# Could not find file <table> in database <dbname> - Progress 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am facing one critical issue in production which is happening randomly. I compiled a. p along with custom tables. And also, respective triggers (WRITE) linked with particular tables in a database which will be fired when the tables get affected. Now the thing is the **. r file is central**, trigger files and custom df loaded in required site (Called site 1).

When I am executing the menu in other site below error I am getting. Note - For other site I cannot promote trigger files and load custom df as it is not needed..in a. p we have a condition to check. If the condition gets success, then only the logic I have written for custom tables get affected. In this scenario except site 1 none of the site the condition will not be satisfied. but I am not sure why am getting this error..do I need to load the df file and linke all trigger files to all the sites even though it is not required? or what is the issue

**/global/mfgpro/opt/prod/global/fin/customcode/xxxx.r --Could not find file  in database . (1494)**

Comment: Stack Overflow questions are supposed to be about specific programming issues. For that to work you need to show some code and clearly describe a problem that you are having with that code. As it stands your question is more along the lines of an opening summary for a long discussion thread. And SO really isn't very good for that purpose. You would be better served to take that kind of inquiry to QAD's support forums or community.progress.com or progresstalk.com

Answer (score 0):

This error message should also generate a protrace. file in the working directory of the session that generated the message.  That protrace should tell you what line number the error occurred on and how you got there.

Comment: Why we are getting this error message there since custom tables and trigger files not required in the site. the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: I have no idea, you haven't shared nearly enough code or configuration to say.